# Page Scrolling Issue: Typing Results in Unwanted Scroll Down

Tags: wolfram-cloud

At times, something goes wrong with the Wolfram Cloud page, and as soon as I click to type, the page automatically scrolls down. Consequently, I end up seeing my written text 2-3 paragraphs below.

This results in the following sequence:

- I type a (SINGLE!) letter,
- it throws me 3 paragraphs down,
- I scroll up,
- I type another (SINGLE!) letter,
- it throws me 3 paragraphs down again,
- I scroll up again,
- I type yet another (SINGLE!) letter,
- it throws me 3 paragraphs down once more,

and so on until the Second Coming.

Alternatively, I can blindly type, staring at an unrelated paragraph or the keyboard and then witness the mess I've written with this blind system. However, how could I fix this issue?